# Spring Boot+Java 9 Modules+Intellij Communicaty Edn: Run configuration behaves differently to jar and mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm trying to learn Spring-Boot with JPA and a H2 embedded db.
I created a repo that replicates my issue [available on github](https://github.com/BarryRRyan/stackoverflowquestion-springboot-jdk15-jpa-h2).
It's based on a tutorial; source found [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa.git.).

My end-state is to run this as a single-module project with all the following methods:

- mvn spring-boot:run
- Run the jar from target in Intellij
- Run the main() method within Intellij

Currently the main() method does something different to the other two approaches, but I don't know why.

If I remove the module-info.java file then all methods exit 0. I know I could ignore it but I'm trying to learn here,
so I want to know what's going on.

Intellij Build Info:

> IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Community Edition) Build #IC-203.7148.57,
> built on January 26, 2021

With jdk 15 set but no module-info.java:

- Run as Intellij Run config. Exit code is 0.
- Run with mvn spring-boot:run. Exit code is 0.
- Run the jar. Exit code is 0.

Add the following module-info.java file to /src/main/java:

```
module demo {
    exports com.example.accessingdatajpa;
    opens com.example.accessingdatajpa;

    requires org.slf4j;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires java.sql;
}
```

Run the application by running main() in intellij and get exit 1:

> c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : Starting AccessingDataJpaApplication using Java 15.0.2 on ...
>
> c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
>
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 166 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
>
> o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:3cb47b25-69e1-4122-bc0f-69447d509171;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
>
> s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
>
> o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:3cb47b25-69e1-4122-bc0f-69447d509171;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'

Run as a jar or with mvn spring-boot:run and get exit code 0:

> ... c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : Starting AccessingDataJpaApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 15.0.2 on ...
> ... c.e.a.AccessingDataJpaApplication        : No active profile set, falling > back to default profiles: default
>
> ... .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA
> repositories in DEFAULT mode.
>
> ... .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository
> scanning in 126 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
>
> ... com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Started.
>
> ... o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was missing the following requires statements in my module-info.java file. Now run, mvn spring-boot:run and running the jar behave the same way.

```
requires java.xml.bind; 
requires net.bytebuddy; 
requires com.fasterxml.classmate;
```

I still don't know *why* this is required for run main() and not the other two approaches. I believe it has something to do with hibernate since I was seeing the following Exception once I added java.xml.bind.

> BeanCreationException (entityManagerFactory ->
> HibernateJpaConfiguration.class)

Looks like I'm being required to specify transitive dependencies explicitly in my module-info.java, something I think I wouldn't have to do if the module declaration of my dependencies used [requires transitive](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity).

Also java.xml.bind is reading javax.activation from two sources now and showing as an error. One of these is coming from **spring-boot-starter-test** despite it being in my test scope. I will update this answer as I learn more.